# JupyterLab: Unable to load file after moving notebook to a new location

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm a newbie to JupyterLab. 
After I physically move a Python notebook to a different directory and try to open it, I'm unable to load it.

The error I get is:
"File Load error for 
Unhandled Error"

If I move the notebook back to the original location, I can load it and work on it. Can someone please advise me how to resolve this?

Perhaps, this issue is unique to the JupyterLab version. Our team has "jupyterlab                1.0.4" installed on our server

Comment: Does it imports any specific module which you wrote ?

Comment: no, I am not importing any modules that I have written.

Comment: can you paste some code of the initial cells? or stack traceback of the error?

Comment: I cannot even open the notebook. so, I'm unable to stack trace. This seems to be an error or exception that is thrown but is not caught by JupyterLab and, as a result, brings the notebook down.

Comment: can you which version you are using `jupyter lab --version`. This error has been an issue with some versions.And you can try upgrading with `conda upgrade -c conda-forge jupyterlab`

Comment: hi Vishal, I had posted the Jupyterlab's version in my original email. It is "jupyterlab 1.0.4"

Comment: sorry. And which jupyter notebook version as well. `jupyter notebook --version`. As i said this issue was there with few earlier versions, it would be great if you could update jupyter notebook and lab to the latest versions

Comment: Vishal, thank you for helping me out. The notebook version is "5.0.0"

Comment: Did you upgraded to latest stable version? and still getting error?

Comment: I don't control the package version. So, in order to convince the on-premise administrator, I have to show some reference that this problem can be resolved by upgrading to a new package. My questions are: 1) Is this issue because we have an older package? 2) If so, which package (lab, notebook, etc.) do I need to upgrade and what version?

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the folder `.ipynb_checkpoints` inside the working directory of the copied file solved the issue for me. Upgrading to the latest version didn't help.