# Can't open Jupyter Notebook files - Unhandled error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been having an issue with Jupyter Notebook where I keep getting error

```
File Load Error for FILENAME.ipynb
Unhandled error
```

I've looked through many posts including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887758/is-there-a-way-to-disable-saving-to-checkpoints-for-jupyter-notebooks/53865194#53865194) that says you can remove the checkpoint folder. I've done that but for some reason it feels like it's ignoring my command

```
c.FileCheckpoints.checkpoint_dir = ''
```

The issue seems to be happening with notebooks I've cloned from our Git repo.
When I look at the Jupyter Server output I can see that it's trying to locate the `checkpoint` file for the file I'm trying to open and it can't find it.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\\\some_folder\\some_folder\\some_folder\\some_folder\\some_folder\\some_folder\\some_folder\\test checkpoints\\some_folder\\.ipynb_checkpoints\\0.Clf_Variable_sig_categorical-checkpoint.ipynb'
```

I don't understand why it's looking for a checkpoint file? How can I get it to not look for this file and just open the file that I'm trying to open?

This error does not happen to all files that I cloned. Some open others don't, and I can't figure out why it would do that?

Also, if I open the same folder with VS Code, then it opens all the files without any issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been going at this for days now and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. **It seems to be caused by moving or renaming a file from within your o/s file-browser**.

Presumably, any hidden Jupyter files containing meta information fail to get updated when you alter the file in your o/s file-browser.

*(I have limited comprehension of what meta information Jupyter keeps where, but there are such things as [default and custom workspaces](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#). I do believe which dir you launch a session from makes a difference to Jupyter).*

My own problem seemed to be that my filename had special chars in it. (eg. `{`). But **I had renamed the file at some point, probably with the o/s file-browser**.

In any case, **I renamed the file using the Jupyter file-browser and Jupyter then opened the file without error**.

I then renamed the file with the Jupyter file-browser again, but this time replacing the special chars that had been in it before - effectively returning the filename to its previous, seemingly offending, state. Jupyter then opened the file.

**So the problem appears to be that I had renamed the file using the o/s file-browser.**

*(It is perhaps possible that the file might have opened if I had attempted it from a Jupyter session launched from a directory where that had never been done before).*

I had noted that this question poster, who reported the same problem, [discovered that it was caused by their filename being too long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68891350/2455413).

Whereas [this poster had the problem after moving the file to a new location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57514761/2455413) *(from within their o/s file-browser, presumably)*.